# Formulário submetido, retorna Class not found autoload Composer

Tags: php, composer

Procurei ver se alguém passou por esse problema mas até agora não encontrei nada na internet. Estou tentando resolver a 2 dias e estou quase desistindo.

**Diretório**

```
index.php
src/
   |__Route/
   |       |__login.php
   |__Dao/
         |__UserDao.php
vendor/
```

**Composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "Src\\": "src/"
     }
}
```

**UserDao.php**

```
<?php
namespace Src\Dao;

class UserDao {}
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
use Src\Dao\UserDao;
```

No meu index.php funciona normalmente, tudo é carregado. O problema surge quando o formulário é submetido, chega no login.php e lança o **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ARQUIVO not found**.

Agradeço desde já, caso alguém souber onde estou errando.

Comment: Você adicionou o require do autoload no arqivo login.php também?

Comment: Se adicionar, vai funcionar. Mas achei que era feito apenas um require do autoload. Não é possível fazer com um único require no arquivo que ira iniciar o sistema?

Comment: Isso seria possível se todas as requisições passassem pelo index.php. Como seu formulario redireciona diretamente ao arquivo login.php, é necessário incluir o autoload nele também

Comment: Seria o conceito de FrontController

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelo feedback Everton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está relacionado ao carregamento do `'vendor/autoload.php';`, é necessário carrega-lo, como você está trabalhando com arquivos php distintos ele é necessário, e no seu caso bastaria adiciona-lo no login.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Src\Dao\UserDao;
```

[*Composer autoloading*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)